# How to cache or get navigation stack in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2

I have a requirement that need to cache the navigation stack.

> Is it possible to **get** or **store** the navigation stack in Ionic 2 ?

So I can restore the navigation history after navigate from other navigation stack.

There is a similar Ionic component that match my requirement, "Ionic Tab".

Ionic Tab can easily switch between different root and keep the navigation stack at the same time.

In my case, I want to use ion-menu (side menu) to do the job.

Any idea or workaround ?